# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask executing doInBackground() in offline mode BufferedReader

Tags: java, android

Okay, well, I'm having an error executing a url via asynctask. When I am logged in everything looks good, if I disconnect from the internet the application hangs when clicking.

**My code is:**

```
String mylinkupdate = "http://www.meusite.com.php?id=" + mList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId();
                    GetXMLTask tasku = new GetXMLTask();
                    tasku.execute(mylinkupdate);
```

**function:**

```
private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String output = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            output = getOutputFromUrl(url);
        }
        return output;
    }



    private String getOutputFromUrl(String url) {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
        try {
            InputStream stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(stream));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                    output.append(s);
            } catch(IOException e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return output.toString();

    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
       // Toast.makeText(mContext,output,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**logcat:**

07-15 14:49:44.649 1806-3467/app.meuapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #7
                                                                              Process: app.meuapp, PID: 1806
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                  at java.io.Reader.(Reader.java:78)
                                                                                  at java.io.InputStreamReader.(InputStreamReader.java:72)
                                                                                  at app.com.asnzapgrupos.meuzapzap.adapters.CarAdapter$GetXMLTask.getOutputFromUrl(CarAdapter.java:981)
                                                                                  at app.com.asnzapgrupos.meuzapzap.adapters.CarAdapter$GetXMLTask.doInBackground(CarAdapter.java:969)
                                                                                  at app.com.asnzapgrupos.meuzapzap.adapters.CarAdapter$GetXMLTask.doInBackground(CarAdapter.java:964)
                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

*thanks*